# What is the purpose of setting Ruby block local variables when blocks have their own scope already?

Tags: ruby, scope, block

Learning about Ruby blocks [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html). What is the point of having block local variable in this example:
[image]

When you can just do the below instead? The `x` in the block is already going to have its own scope, which is different than the `x` that is outside the block.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Block scopes *nest* inside their lexically enclosing scope:

```
foo = :outerfoo
bar = :outerbar

1.times do |;bar|
  foo = :innerfoo
  bar = :innerbar
  baz = :innerbaz
end

foo #=> :innerfoo
bar #=> :outerbar
baz # NameError
```

You need a way to tell Ruby: "I don't want this variable from the outer scope, I want a fresh one." That's what block local variables do.

Comment: how is the 2nd example not already getting a fresh variable when it prints 0 thru 4 instead of 10 thru 14?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. There are no nested variables in the second example. `x` is a parameter of the block, not a variable.

Comment: so adding `;` is the only way for the block scope to get variables from the outer scope?

Comment: No, the semicolon makes it so that the scopes will be separate. If `x` isn't mentioned between the pipes at all, then `x` will refer to the variable in the outer scope (if it exists).

Comment: why does your baz get error? It wasn't declared in the outer scope, but it was declared in the inner scope so should it be equal to :innerbaz just like how foo was set to :innerfoo inside block? Is there something in Ruby that allows reassignment inside blocks but not creation of variables?

Comment: @stackjlei: `baz` is a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, that's why they are called "local variables". `baz` is defined inside the block, it is local to the block.

Comment: Is there anyway to reference the value of the outer variable while using this? Like `bar = outer_bar`?

Comment: I don't understand, in the original example, whether x and y depend on outer or inner, they have to be reassigned in the block, and the result makes no difference

Answer (score 4):

The point they're trying to make is that a *block local variable* (or a block parameter) will be completely separate from the variable outside of the block even if they have the same name, but if you just refer to `x` within the block without it being a block local variable or a block parameter, you're referring to the same `x` that exists outside the block.

They have this example right above the one you cite:

```
            x = 10
            5.times do |y|
              x = y
              puts "x inside the block: #{x}"
            end

            puts "x outside the block: #{x}"
```

Output:

```
            x inside the block: 0
            x inside the block: 1
            x inside the block: 2
            x inside the block: 3
            x inside the block: 4
            x outside the block: 4
```

Note that this is only the case if you refer to `x` before the block. If you removed the `x = 10` line at the beginning, then the `x` in the block would be completely local to the block and that last line would error out (unless you had a method named `x` in the same object, in which case it would call that method).

Comment: sorry my 2nd example before was wrong, please take a look again at it. the x inside the block doesn't refer to the outside x, but a new one side. so why would you need to use the `;` specifically in the first example to declare a local variable when it's already local without the `;`?

Comment: In your second example, `x` is a block parameter, which also has a separate scope. But if it isn't either a block parameter or a block local variable (notice that it's just `y` between the pipes in the example I copied from the page), then `x` inside the block does refer to the outer scope. I'll edit to note that it's true of both block parameters and block local variables.

Comment: Why "x outside" is also 4, I thought it should be 10

Comment: @TPR, its because in that example, ```x``` is a block variable and is being passed directly to the method.  It has nothing to do with anything outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the examples given in the original post leave a lot to be desired and largely serve to further confuse matters because the results of `|y; x|` and `|y, x|` are going to be identical.  So the obvious question becomes this:

Why would we ever need to use a semicolon to create a `block local variable` if simply creating a regular block variable does the same thing?

I think the answer is that you would want to use `;` instead of `,` anytime you want to **BOTH** protect the outer variable from manipulation **AND** declare an inner variable that will NOT be passed to the `method`.

Consider for example what happens with `multiple assignment` or `hash` when working with the `map` method:

```
x = 10
array = [[1], [:a]]
hash = {:b => 2}   

array.map {|y| x = y}  #=>  [[1], [:a]]
x  #=>  [:a]  
array.map {|y, x| x = y}  #=>  [1, :a]
x  #=>  10 
array.map {|y; x| x = y}  #=>  [[1], [:a]]
x  #=>  10

hash.map {|y| x = y}  #=>  [[:b, 2]]
x  #=>  [:b, 2]
hash.map {|y, x| x = y}  #=>  [:b]
x  #=>  10
hash.map {|y; x| x = y}  #=>  [[:b, 2]]
x  #=>  10
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the output of each hash

Comment: @TPR, explaining ```#Hash.map``` logic really wasn’t my intent.  For that you should probably read the documentation or post an appropriate question.  The point I was trying to make was that contrary to some of the suppositions, there ARE differences between regular block variables and explicitly declared block local variables depending on the object, method, and desired output.  You don’t really even have to understand what the code is doing to see the point I was trying to make.

Comment: why "array.map {|y| x = y}" made x to [:a]

Answer (score 0):

The examples above are teaching you about block scopes and how inner scopes can mute outer scopes (your `x` variable).  The point is that you have to be aware of the differences.

Comment: it seems like a block will always mute outer scope looking at example 2. that's why i'm asking what is the point of example 1